Entity is already being tracked error when adding to database
I am getting the following error when I attempt to add something to my database:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'IngredientCategory' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 15}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

This is the line that throws the error in the view model:
context.Ingredients.Add(newItem);

View model:
public partial class IngredientViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    RecipeDBContext context;

    private Ingredient _ingredient = new Ingredient();
    public Ingredient Ingredient => _ingredient;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Ingredient> _ingredients;

    public List<IngredientCategory> Categories { get; set; }
 
    public IngredientViewModel()
    {
        context = new RecipeDBContext();            
        _ingredients = new ObservableCollection<Ingredient>();
        UpdateIngredients(context.Ingredients.ToList());
        _ingredients.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
        Categories= context.IngredientCategories.Where(p => p.ParentId != null).ToList();    
    }
 
    public void UpdateIngredients(List<Ingredient> ingredients)
    {
        Ingredients.Clear();    

        foreach (Ingredient ingredient in ingredients)
        {       
            Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
        }
    }

    void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {        
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Ingredient newItem in e.NewItems)
            {           
                context.Ingredients.Add(newItem);
            }        
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Ingredient oldItem in e.OldItems)
            {            
                context.Ingredients.Remove(oldItem);                        
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

Xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="RecipeApp.Views.Dialogs.AddIngredientDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RecipeApp.Views.Dialogs"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:models="using:RecipeApp.Models" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:Supplier}"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:RecipeApp.ViewModels" 
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    Title="Save your work?"
    PrimaryButtonText="Save"    
    CloseButtonText="Cancel"
    DefaultButton="Primary"
    Width="1000"
    Height="1000">

    <ContentDialog.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/FormUI.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox"  x:Key="ValidatedTextBox2">
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="50" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentDialog.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Header="Name" PlaceholderText="Enter Name" PlaceholderForeground="Gray"  IsColorFontEnabled="True" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Ingredient.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="DescTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap"  AcceptsReturn="True" SelectionHighlightColor="Green" MinWidth="400" Width="600" Height="300" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Ingredient.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ingredientCategoryBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Categories}" SelectionChanged="ingredientCategoryBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:IngredientCategory">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.Ingredient.HasErrors, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 50 0 0">
            <TextBlock FontSize="20">Errors:</TextBlock>
            <Border Background="Gray">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ErrorsBox"  Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Ingredient.Errors, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>

Code behind file
public sealed partial class AddIngredientDialog : ContentDialog
{    
    public IngredientViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();

    public AddIngredientDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ingredientCategoryBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Ingredient.Category = ingredientCategoryBox.SelectedItem as IngredientCategory;
    }
}

Category model class:
public class IngredientCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public IngredientCategory Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public Ingredient IngredientId { get; set; }
    public IngredientCategory() {}

    public IngredientCategory(int id, string name, int parentId)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        ParentId = parentId;
    }
}

Ingredient model class:
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public partial class Ingredient: BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Name should be longer than one character")]
    private string _name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _description;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _categoryId;
    public IngredientCategory Category { get; set; }

    //public Ingredient(string name, IngredientCategory category)

    public Ingredient()
    {
        SetProperty(ref _name, _name, true, nameof(Name));
    }      
    /*
    ~Ingredient()
    {
        ErrorsChanged -= Errors_Changed;
        PropertyChanged -= Property_Changed;
    }
    */
    public Ingredient(string name, string description, IngredientCategory category)
    {
        if (category == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("category was null for " + name);
        }
        else
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            CategoryId = category.Id;
            //Category = category;
        }
    }
}


This question is similar to: instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with same key value is tracked. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
